# How to show banner ad only for mobile users?

Tags: php, mobile, ads, banner, feature-detection

I have some static pages with both desktop and mobile visitors.
Is it possible to show a banner on them only for mobile visitors?
PHP solutions are also OK.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following methods:

- [PHP Mobile Detection](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/lightweight-device-detection-php)
- Touch event Detection:

`

```
var mobile = !!('createTouch' in document) && (document['createTouch']);
```

**References**

- [Lightweight Device-Detection in PHP](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/lightweight-device-detection-php)
- [Touch Events](https://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/)